# Generating an Scaffold with a different name from the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, scaffolding

Is is posible to generate and scaffold for an existing model with a different name not associated directly to the name of my model?

Let's say I have this model `Post` and I already have a controller named `posts_controller` but I have a bunch of methods there that I'm already using, but as a matter of time I need to generate an scaffold to fill in my table posts trough the model `Post` but if I try

`rails g scaffold Post field:type.... --skip--migration`

The generator would still be looking to create a controller named `posts_controller` is is possible to specify the controller name It'd using/generating to something like: `my_awesome_scaffold_controller` ?

Thanks.

======= UPDATE ========

What I want to have in `my_awesome_scaffold_controller` is the complete scaffold for my model post `index`, `new`, `edit`, `show`, `create`, `update`, `delete` for the `Post` model without using the `post_controller` with is already in use for other stuff done by somebody else and I don't wanna mess up the code there.

Comment: sorry, can you explain a bit more why you need to do this? What are you putting into my_awesome_posts_controller that can't go in posts_controller ? (us understanding will help us figure out what you need)

Comment: @TarynEast Just updated the question body.

Answer (score 1):

ok... I'm not convinced that what you're doing is better than just, say, moving the existing posts_controller away somewhere else (eg a library or whatever) but to stay true to what you actually asked...

One option (if you don't mind adding the actions back into posts_controller)

1. copy "post_controller.rb" to somewhere else
2. run scaffold as per normal with "post" (it will be named posts_cotroller.rb)
3. rename "posts-controller.rb" to "my_awesome_posts_controller.rb"
4. copy back posts_controller.rb
5. pull everything out of "my-awesome" and paste it into the top/bottom of existing posts_controller.rb

obviously this won't work if the posts_controller already has any of the RESTful actions - also it means you and the other person are working on the same file (though likely different areas).

Alternatively you could name-space your scaffold. Similar to `admin/posts_controller.rb` (or in your case: `my_awesome/posts_controller.rb`)

There's an old tutorial on this here: http://icebergist.com/posts/restful-admin-namespaced-controller-using-scaffolding
Can't vouch for how good/relevant it is for you.

Comment: my brain just caught up with me - this of course wouldn't work as all the views etc would expect PostsController

Comment: Yes, routes for the new controller would be messed up... I think I'll make a code refectory and/or do the CRUD somewhere else, thanks.

Comment: Actually that comment was for my answer *before* this edit :)

The tutorial shows how to update your views to make them work with the nested controller.